# How to extrude a cylinder from plane without ngons?

Tags: modeling

So basically I want to extrude a cylinder (pipe in my model) from plane. I can do it easily with subdividing plane, delete faces from the center and then us To Sphere command. But problem is that this workflow will produce ngons on plane attached to this particular face.

Any ways to do it without ngons/making loop cuts all over the place?

[image: ngons]

Comment: Depending on the model purpose you can go with much less loopcuts and use Subsurf on the final model once the extruding is ready, but no way to avoid Ngons without adding more geometry to the empty face to the right. What you can do is optimize loops coming out of the hole so joining them from 3 to 1, from 5 to 3 and so on, there are certain techniques, see http://topologyguides.com/post/163679954765/loop-reduction

Comment: The proposed workflow does not create ngons. If you started with quads, the To Sphere command will not turn those quads into ngons.

Comment: @cegaton Yeah that's true. The problem is that I would want to make that hole from plane without need to add loop cuts to the plane on the right. I'm making a pipe which comes out of wall. It would be nice to make so that no need to add loop cuts all of the walls,

Comment: @heisenberg You can crease the edge loop with *Shift+E* instead of adding the loop cuts.